# azure web jobs swap in secondary slot in app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a web site running in azure app service.
And it has also **web jobs** deployed.

Now I am creating a new slot for my app service, and deploying the web site code to the new slot.

When I swap the slots, the web jobs still run in the production slot or would they be swap to the new slot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Under the covers, Webjobs live in your App Service's site \ wwwroot \ App_data \ jobs \ continuous | triggered folder. A slot swap is a [set of actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#what-happens-during-a-swap) that are performed that ultimately end in a routing rule switch within Azure.

Your webjobs will participate in a slot swap for the App Service.

However, there are some interesting corner cases. For example, let's assume that your staging and production application settings are identical and you have triggers defined for something like a ServiceBusTrigger. Unless you stop your staging slot Webjobs, your staging Webjob instance triggers will continue to poll your production resources, meaning you can be executing both your production and slot Webjob code.

Answer (score 0):

Webjob too will be swapped for sure. There's a config setting to stop all webjobs within a deployment slot (`WEBJOBS_STOPPED = 1`), but there isn't something to stop just the specific ones within a slot, as far as I know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).